# Create Trigger to display message “Restock- <item-name>”, when a item quantity reaches 10 and below while updating or inserting item

Tags: oracle, plsql

**table**

```
Stock:

ITEMID                            NUMBER          PRIMARY KEY
DESCRIPTION                    VARCHAR2(30) 
QUANTITY                          NUMBER
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_1 BEFORE
    UPDATE OR INSERT ON stock
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    v_des    VARCHAR2(30);
    v_quan   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT
        quantity,
        description
    INTO
        v_quan,
        v_des
    FROM
        stock;

    IF v_quan <= 10 THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Restock' || v_des);
    END IF;

END;
```

Comment: do you mean the total quantity, or the current quantity for the newly inserted record?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `:NEW` cursor to refer to the new value that is being inserted or updated as following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIG_1 BEFORE
    UPDATE OR INSERT ON STOCK
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.QUANTITY <= 10 THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Restock - ' || :NEW.DESCRIPTION);
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Make sure that you `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` while inserting/updating the table data so that it is displayed in the output.

Cheers!!

Comment: I guess it must be :NEW.QUANTITY <= 10, as user is checking for the existing value in the table not the new inserting one.